# React Tailwindcss dropdown doesn't open. Click on the dropdown button but dropdown dont open

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

I'm tryinng to use react tailwind css navbar. Everything is all right but dropdown is not working. I clicked on the icon but never open dropdown. I can't found the problem. Please help me out to finding whats the wrong in my code. I'm using typescript in my project.Please Tell me Whats going on in my code.

### Menu Code

```
<Menu as="div" className="relative ml-3">
                  <div>
                    <Menu.Button className="flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800">
                      <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                      <img
                        className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                        alt=""
                      />
                    </Menu.Button>
                  </div>
                  <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                    enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                    leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                  >
                    <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                      <Menu.Item>
                        {({ active }) => (
                          <a
                            href="#"
                            className={classNames(
                              active ? "bg-gray-100" : "",
                              "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700"
                            )}
                          >
                            Your Profile
                          </a>
                        )}
                      </Menu.Item>
                    </Menu.Items>
                  </Transition>
                </Menu>
```

### My Package.json

```
{
  "name": "e-shop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^0.0.0-dev.0ce63d8",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.16",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "flowbite": "^1.6.3",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.3.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

### tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("flowbite/plugin")],
  include: ["src/**/*.ts*"],
};
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-ui-forked-vmy8qd?file=/src/App.js
Strange its working here

Comment: but in my computer it is not work